How to assert an exception that is logged and is not affecting the Response
I'm testing an API that can raise an exception, but eventually returns a response based on other calculations, not related to the exception that is raised (it only logs the exception):
def get(self, request):
    #some code here
    try:
        #do something and create the response value
    except Exception as err:
        logger.exception(str(err))
    return Response

I tried the following to test if an exception is raised, but it didn't work as the final return value (API's response) doesn't care about the exception:
with pytest.raises(RuntimeError):
    response = MyInfo.as_view(
    )(request)

I get the following:
>       with pytest.raises(RuntimeError):
E       Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'RuntimeError'> 

even though a RuntimeError exception is logged. I think pytest only cares about the API's response and not an exception that has occurred inside the API.
--------- EDIT --------
There is a suggestion for the use of caplog.
Since I'm using @patch above my test function, I can't pass 'caplog' as an argument to the function. I tried this suggested method inside my conftest.py as follows:
@pytest.fixture() 
def my_caplog(caplog): 
    with caplog.at_level(logging.INFO): 
        yield 
    print(caplog.text)

but nothing gets printed. Not sure how to use it in this case.

Unless your MWE is not representation of your code, except Exception will catch all non-system-exiting exceptions - that’s why your pytest isn’t seeing an exception. Narrow your exception block or re-raise.

Can you clarify what you meant with "narrow the exception"? what options do I have?

Have you reviewed the caplog fixture?
One option would be to do something like
def test_raises_exception(caplog):
    assert "exception" in caplog.text.lower()


Updated the example
import logging
from unittest.mock import patch

class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        pass

class TestFoo:
    @patch.object(Foo, "bar")
    def test_stuff(self, mock_bar, caplog):
        logging.exception("ERROR")
        assert "ERROR" in caplog.text


Thanks for the suggestion. I'm using @patch above my test function and I can't pass 'caplog' as an argument to the function. I tried the method you suggested inside my conftest.py but it didn't work. please see my 'edit' in the post.

@brainoverflow patch will not affect the usage. When you use patch, the first argument to the test function will be the mock, the second can be caplog.

this is what I get when I add it after arguments self, and mock:
TypeError: .<test_name()> missing 1 required positional argument: 'caplog'

@brainoverflow Is the test part of a class? Either way check your code. I updated my answer with a proven working example.

yes, it's part of a class. I still get the same error when the first argument is "self".
TypeError: <test_name>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'caplog'
